# Handling Digital ID/Signature in Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, digital-signature

I have a C# Outlook Add-In application (VS2005 and 2003 Outlook) that reads incoming emails and strips out the attachments and the email text body for future processing.  Occasionally I'll get an email that contains a digital signature.  The application will fail when I try to access the mailitem.body property, throwing the following exception:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xAB404001): The operation failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_Body()
   at MyLib.MyApp.OutlookAddin.MailProcessor.ProcessMailItem(MailItem mailItem)

I'm pretty sure it is the digital signature causing the problem because if I forward the email back to myself, it will strip off the original sender's digital signature and the add-in application will process the email without any problems.  I'm not sure what to do.  I need to process the email, so I can't just ignore it.  Somehow getting the body of the original email without throwing an exception would be ideal.  Or I guess if I can identify that there is a digital signature associated with the email, I could forward the email to myself, but that seems a little messy.  Does anyone have any suggestions/fixes?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: We are having the very same problem. What more, the HRESULT is variable (only the last 4001 part will remain fixed)

Answer (score 1):

A followup.  What I ended up doing was throwing the get_body call in a try..catch block.  If there was an error, I moved the email to another Outlook folder for manual processing.  Here is a link to the question that I posted on Microsoft's forum and a response that I received.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d8b29cff-7656-4440-920a-21047c1ff82f